# Should I use Destructor when I inherit from IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, destructor

I am creating a ServiceLayer for my EntityFramework.

The service layer uses the Repositories which implements IDisposable. Since I am not implementing IDisposable in my Service class, should I use the Destructor to dispose object, or they will be automatically disposed by GC.

```
public class ProductService
{
    private readonly ProductRepository _productRepository;

    public ProductService(ProductRepository repo)
    {
        _productRepository = repo;
    }

    ......
    ......

    ~ProductService()
    {
        _productRepositort.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: Who creates repository instances?

Comment: You should only implement a destructor/finalizer when you need to clean up UNMANAGED resources (such as handles, pointers to unmanaged stuff etc). And even then shouldn't you create a finalizer, but rather use the SafeHandle or a related class. So: noo! You don't need that finalizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disposing has nothing to do with the garbage collector. It's more about closing database connections, file handles, etc.

If you are using something that is disposable, your class should be disposable too and dispose of those items using the [dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

> Since I am not implementing IDisposable in my Service class, should I
>   use the Destructor to dispose object

You *must not* call `IDisposable.Dispose` in finalizer, because it is intended for unmanaged resources cleanup. And, after appearance of [`SafeHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you should consider using `SafeHandle` instead of implementing finalizer.

You *must* call `IDisposable.Dispose` elsewhere, because GC doesn't call `Dispose`, when it frees object's memory. The place and the moment, when you'll call `Dispose`, depends on who, where and when creates `IDisposable` implementation.

Usually, `Dispose` is called by the object, who was created `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the scope of the reposytory instance.  Where is it created and for how long object is available.  Or do you register repository with DI?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IoC that creates this ProductService and that ProductRepository has some LifeTime, then that IoC should call DisposeproductRepository. It's usefull for Web Application and when lifetime is set to just one HttpRequest.

If you use ProductRepository  without `using` keyword or you don't call Dispose method manually, then Dispose won't be called by GC. GC will call just destructor, and it doesn't call Dispose method.

Answer (score -3):

See the IDisposable pattern here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx